# How to measure supply constraints/bottlenecks

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, supply-and-demand, data-request

A common explanation for the recent global surge in inflation points to supply constraints and bottlenecks in delivery chains. While I find the argument appealing, I have seen little quantitative evidence for the role of such factors. What type of numerical measures could one use to assess such constraints/bottlenecks? Ultimately I am looking for a macro level indicator, but industry level measures could be a good starting point.

Comment: You could look at number of ships waiting to dock - I've seen numerous articles about cargo ships waiting in long lines to load/unload.

Comment: @RegressForward Thank you. Is such data easily available (especially at aggregated level)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are aggregate and industry level measures that at least indirectly measure supply chain pressures, most notably:

- **Purchasing Managers Index (PMI) subindex "Suppliers' delivery times"** (now from S&P Global, after it bought IHS Markit). Unfortunately one needs to pay a fee (expensive), or have for example access to Datastream that includes the PMI package. This is monthly frequency, and available for main industries & countries. See global chart below for the global aggregate.
  [image]
- The New York Feds' [**Global Supply Chain Pressure Index**](https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/policy/gscpi#/interactive) (GSCPI). For the methodology, see [here](https://libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org/2022/05/global-supply-chain-pressure-index-may-2022-update/). Monthly frequency. The methodology bit refers to further sources, which might be of interest on their own.

The World Bank also has an [index](https://lpi.worldbank.org/international/global), but this it's based on structural factors and very low frequencey (not even annual), and the latest data is from 2018. There are also quite a few more proprietary indices, such as from [Achilles](https://pages.achilles.com/achilles-supply-chain-resilience-index-download-it-now?_gl=1*rc4u9t*_ga*MTkwMDQ1NDk3OS4xNjU4NzM4MzA2*_ga_C6402DSD6K*MTY1ODczODMwNS4xLjAuMTY1ODczODMwNi41OQ..), or from [Moody's](https://www.moodysanalytics.com/microsites/data-solutions/supplier-risk-management?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_viWBhD8ARIsAH1mCd5IzsRoKkU5qtotc6ELY4OOaKXGLE5bwzVoLbN_sK6h2rUE3su8hPoaAsSfEALw_wcB), but they are all paid.

Note that while there are these metrics, it is not always clear a priori, how exactly these feed into inflation. An exception are the the [Harpex](https://www.harperpetersen.com/harpex) and [air freight costs](https://www.bls.gov/mxp/publications/factsheets/air-freight-facts.htm), which are cost indices and both subindices of the GSCPI mentioned above.